# REST API - Exclude fields by default

Tags: json, rest, api

I am currently having a trouble designing my API. This is my first draft:

```
Endpoint: /api/v1/orders/{id}/tracking

{
    "state": "on_the_way",
    "location": {
        "latitude": -6.123,
        "longitude": 102.123
    },
    "distance": {
        "value": 10,
        "unit": "meters"
    },
    "duration": {
        "value": 10,
        "unit": "minutes"
    }
}
```

It turns out, the product team wants it to have `distance` and `duration` be excluded by default, because it is using the Google Maps's Distance Matrix API, and it will affect our billing. How would the query parameters look like if I want to show the `distance` and `duration`?

Is there any idiomatic way to do this? I don't think I can use sparse fieldset, includes, or excludes here.

Answer (score 0):

`/api/v1/orders/{id}/tracking/full`

to include distance and duration. I tend to consider parameters as `RPC` rather than `REST`. e.g. `/tracking?type=full`

`/api/v1/orders/{id}/tracking`

would then be the default endpoint for only state and location.

You could use HATEOS to include full tracking url in the response.